# Save custom columns view

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to save the custom columns view for future use?

It is more convenient to enter directly to the custom view suitable for my use.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, but we are actively working on building this capability in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) as part of our [Saved Entry Views](https://trello.com/c/T0qvZ1uq/121-saved-entry-views) feature.  Please up-vote or comment on this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board).